# Is it possible to sandbox JavaScript running in the browser?

Tags: javascript, browser, sandbox

I'm wondering if it's possible to sandbox JavaScript running in the browser to prevent access to features that are normally available to JavaScript code running in an HTML page.

For example, let's say I want to provide a JavaScript API for end users to let them define event handlers to be run when "interesting events" happen, but I don't want those users to access the properties and functions of the `window` object. Am I able to do this?

In the simplest case, let's say I want to prevent users calling `alert`. A couple of approaches I can think of are:

- Redefine `window.alert` globally. I don't think this would be a valid approach because other code running in the page (i.e., stuff not authored by users in their event handlers) might want to use `alert`.
- Send the event handler code to the server to process. I'm not sure that sending the code to the server to process is the right approach, because the event handlers need to run in the context of the page.

Perhaps a solution where the server processes the user defined function and then generates a callback to be executed on the client would work? Even if that approach works, are there better ways to solve this problem?

Answer (score 55):

[Google Caja](https://github.com/google/caja) is a source-to-source translator that "allows you to put untrusted third-party HTML and JavaScript inline in your page and still be secure."

Comment: A quick test shows that Caja is unable to protect the browser from CPU attacks like `while (1) {}` --- it just hangs. Likewise `a=[]; while (1) { a=[a,a]; }`.

Comment: Yes, denial of service is out of scope: https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/issues/detail?id=1406

Comment: Project will be deprecated by Google January 31st 2021. They're recommending people move to Closure library (https://github.com/google/closure-library) instead.

Comment: Closure just announced (2023/11/05) that it too will be deprecated August 1st 2024.

Answer (score 33):

Have a look at [Douglas Crockford's ADsafe](http://www.adsafe.org/):

> ADsafe makes it safe to put guest code (such as third party scripted advertising or widgets) on any web page. ADsafe defines a subset of JavaScript that is powerful enough to allow guest code to perform valuable interactions, while at the same time preventing malicious or accidental damage or intrusion. The ADsafe subset can be verified mechanically by tools like JSLint so that no human inspection is necessary to review guest code for safety. The ADsafe  subset also enforces good coding practices, increasing the likelihood that guest code will run correctly.

You can see an example of how to use ADsafe by looking at the `template.html` and `template.js` files in [the project's GitHub repository](https://github.com/douglascrockford/ADsafe).

Comment: On their site, I see no way of using ADsafe. There is no way to download it, no link to the code, nothing. How can you try out ADsafe?

Comment: Also, it prevents *any* access to `this`, which is entirely unacceptable. You can't write good javascript without using `this`.

Comment: There's a link to [the code on GitHub](https://github.com/douglascrockford/ADsafe) from the bottom of the [ADsafe Widget Structure](http://www.adsafe.org/widget.html) page.

Comment: @BT I've written entire projects without using `this`. It's not hard to avoid the poorly-named parameter.

Comment: @mindeavor Then you've entirely foregone all object-oriented javascript. I would say that's unacceptable.

Comment: @BT It'd be silly to say that completing real-world projects is unacceptable. But I regret starting this discussion, and must withdraw; this is not the place to discuss such things (sorry). I'm on twitter if you want to discuss further.

Comment: @mindeavor Real world projects use object-oriented programming and `this`. Please do withdraw, your arugment is garbage. Not allowing `this` means valid javascript fails. Its a recipe for being a pain in the ass. Yes you *could* do it, but by definition guest code isn't *you*, its someone else - the guest. And telling them they can't use any library that uses `this` means they're going to give you a big middle finger and never integrate with your crap.

Comment: @BT (I'll continue since it's relevant to the question) Anytime you run code in someone else's environment you will run into rules and restrictions. I would not call that unacceptable. A "pain in the ass", maybe. But not unacceptable. After all, for every use of `this`, there is an equal, equivalent non-`this` way to do it (it's just a parameter, after all).

Comment: how to use this? i dont see any documentation at all

Comment: @slier I've edited my answer with detail of where you can see an example of using ADsafe.

Answer (score 23):

I created a sandboxing library called [jsandbox](https://github.com/eligrey/jsandbox) that uses web workers to sandbox evaluated code. It also has an input method for explicitly giving sandboxed code data it wouldn't otherwise be able to get.

The following is an example of the API:

```
jsandbox
    .eval({
      code    : "x=1;Math.round(Math.pow(input, ++x))",
      input   : 36.565010597564445,
      callback: function(n) {
          console.log("number: ", n); // number: 1337
      }
  }).eval({
      code   : "][];.]\\ (*# ($(! ~",
      onerror: function(ex) {
          console.log("syntax error: ", ex); // syntax error: [error object]
      }
  }).eval({
      code    : '"foo"+input',
      input   : "bar",
      callback: function(str) {
          console.log("string: ", str); // string: foobar
      }
  }).eval({
      code    : "({q:1, w:2})",
      callback: function(obj) {
          console.log("object: ", obj); // object: object q=1 w=2
      }
  }).eval({
      code    : "[1, 2, 3].concat(input)",
      input   : [4, 5, 6],
      callback: function(arr) {
          console.log("array: ", arr); // array: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
      }
  }).eval({
      code    : "function x(z){this.y=z;};new x(input)",
      input   : 4,
      callback: function(x) {
          console.log("new x: ", x); // new x: object y=4
      }
  });
```

Comment: +1: This looks really cool. How safe is to execute user's code this way?

Comment: Very safe. Check out the updated library [on github](https://github.com/eligrey/jsandbox).

Comment: is this project still maintained? I see it has not been updated since over 2 years...

Comment: I like this, except that if you want to sandbox but still allow the code access to say jQuery, this would fail as web workers do not allow DOM manipulation.

Comment: Hi Eli - thanks for a great lib, are you planning to maintain it? I've a change request for adding debugging functionality - which by quick looking at the code should be possible. Please let me know what you think?

Comment: @Rahly: Anything that is allowed to manipulate the DOM is, by definition, unsafe. How do you imagine you would sandbox DOM access?

Comment: In theory? You would create a document fragment that is jailed, where any manipulations/traversals are a limited by the fragment tree.

Comment: wow that's ... intriguing! @Rahly

Answer (score 14):

An improved version of [RyanOHara's web workers sandbox code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195149/is-it-possible-to-sandbox-javascript-running-in-the-browser/24562400#24562400), in a **single file** (no extra `eval.js` file is necessary).

```
function safeEval(untrustedCode)
{
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject)
        {
            var blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([
                "(",
                function ()
                {
                    var _postMessage = postMessage;
                    var _addEventListener = addEventListener;

                    (function (obj)
                    {
                        "use strict";

                        var current = obj;
                        var keepProperties =
                        [
                            // Required
                            'Object', 'Function', 'Infinity', 'NaN', 'undefined', 'caches', 'TEMPORARY', 'PERSISTENT',
                            // Optional, but trivial to get back
                            'Array', 'Boolean', 'Number', 'String', 'Symbol',
                            // Optional
                            'Map', 'Math', 'Set',
                        ];

                        do
                        {
                            Object.getOwnPropertyNames(current).forEach(function (name)
                            {
                                if (keepProperties.indexOf(name) === -1)
                                {
                                    delete current[name];
                                }
                            });

                            current = Object.getPrototypeOf(current);
                        }
                        while (current !== Object.prototype)
                            ;

                    })(this);

                    _addEventListener("message", function (e)
                    {
                        var f = new Function("", "return (" + e.data + "\n);");
                        _postMessage(f());
                    });
                }.toString(),
                ")()"],
                {type: "application/javascript"}));

                var worker = new Worker(blobURL);

                URL.revokeObjectURL(blobURL);

                worker.onmessage = function (evt)
                {
                    worker.terminate();
                    resolve(evt.data);
                };

                worker.onerror = function (evt)
                {
                    reject(new Error(evt.message));
                };

                worker.postMessage(untrustedCode);

                setTimeout(function ()
                {
                    worker.terminate();
                    reject(new Error('The worker timed out.'));
                }, 1000);
        });
}
```

Test it:

https://jsfiddle.net/kp0cq6yw/

```
var promise = safeEval("1+2+3");

promise.then(function (result) {
                 alert(result);
             });
```

It should output `6` (tested in Chrome and Firefox).

Answer (score 12):

As mentioned in other responces, it's enough to jail the code in a sandboxed iframe (without sending it to the server-side) and communicate with messages.

I would suggest to take a look at [a small library](https://github.com/asvd/jailed) I created mostly because of the need to providing some API to the untrusted code, just like as described in the question: there's an opportunity to export the particular set of functions right into the sandbox where the untrusted code runs. And there's also a demo which executes the code submitted by a user in a sandbox:

http://asvd.github.io/jailed/demos/web/console/

Answer (score 9):

I think that [js.js](https://github.com/jterrace/js.js) is worth mentioning here. It's a JavaScript interpreter written in JavaScript.

It's about 200 times slower than native JavaScript, but its nature makes it a perfect sandbox environment. Another drawback is its size – almost 600 KB, which may be acceptable for desktops in some cases, but not for mobile devices.

Answer (score 6):

All the browser vendors and the HTML5 specification are working towards an actual sandbox property to allow sandboxed iframes -- but it's still limited to iframe granularity.

In general, no degree of regular expressions, etc. can safely sanitise arbitrary user provided JavaScript as it degenerates to the halting problem :-/

Comment: Can you explain how it degenerates to the halting problem?

Comment: The theoretic impossibility of solving the halting problem only really applies to static code analysis. Sandboxes can do things like enforce time limits to deal with the halting problem.

Answer (score 2):

An ugly way, but maybe this works for you:

I took all the globals and redefined them in the sandbox scope, as well I added the strict mode so they can't get the global object using an anonymous function.

```
function construct(constructor, args) {
  function F() {
      return constructor.apply(this, args);
  }
  F.prototype = constructor.prototype;
  return new F();
}
// Sanboxer
function sandboxcode(string, inject) {
  "use strict";
  var globals = [];
  for (var i in window) {
    // <--REMOVE THIS CONDITION
    if (i != "console")
    // REMOVE THIS CONDITION -->
    globals.push(i);
  }
  globals.push('"use strict";\n'+string);
  return construct(Function, globals).apply(inject ? inject : {});
}
sandboxcode('console.log( this, window, top , self, parent, this["jQuery"], (function(){return this;}()));');
// => Object {} undefined undefined undefined undefined undefined undefined
console.log("return of this", sandboxcode('return this;', {window:"sanboxed code"}));
// => Object {window: "sanboxed code"}
```

https://gist.github.com/alejandrolechuga/9381781

Comment: Trivial to get `window` back from that. `sandboxcode('console.log((0,eval)("this"))')`

Comment: I'll have to figure out how to prevent that

Comment: @alejandro Did you find a way to prevent that?

Comment: Broke my head until I just realized you can do ```eval = 0``` globally before calling the sandbox (storing the original function in a temp) and then both global ```window.eval``` and ```eval``` wont be accessible. Next Hack please! Because I actually consider this option.

Comment: My implementation just adds:
```function sbx(s,p) {e = eval; eval = function(t){console.log("GOT GOOD")}; sandboxcode(s,p); eval =e}```

Comment: @YoniXw: I hope you didn’t end up using it for anything. No approach like this will ever work. `(_=>_).constructor('return this')()`

Comment: There's no nice way to do it you can always do this and you'll have access, with an IIFE


`function sandboxcode(string, inject) {
  "use strict";
  return (new Function(\`const window = {}; var_this = this; const console = this.console;   ${string}\`)).call({console});
}
sandboxcode('console.log(function(){ return this}())');`

Answer (score 2):

An independent JavaScript interpreter is more likely to yield a robust sandbox than a caged version of the built-in browser implementation.

Ryan has [already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24562400/120398) [js.js](https://github.com/jterrace/js.js), but a more up-to-date project is [JS-Interpreter](https://github.com/NeilFraser/JS-Interpreter). [The documentation](https://neil.fraser.name/software/JS-Interpreter/docs.html) covers how to expose various functions to the interpreter, but its scope is otherwise very limited.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2019, [vm2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vm2) looks like the most popular and most regularly-updated solution to running JavaScript *in Node.js*. I'm not aware of a front-end solution.

Comment: vm2 does not support runtime in the browser.  It should, however, work if you're looking to sandbox code in a nodejs app.

Answer (score 0):

With [NISP](https://github.com/ysmood/nisp) you'll be able to do sandboxed evaluation.

Though the expression you write is not exactly JavaScript code, instead you'll write [S-expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-expression). It is ideal for simple [DSLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) that doesn't demand extensive programming.

Answer (score -3):

1. Suppose you have code to execute:

   ```
    var sCode = "alert(document)";
   ```

   Now, suppose you want to execute it in a sandbox:

   ```
    new Function("window", "with(window){" + sCode + "}")({});
   ```

   These two lines when executed will fail, because "alert" function is not available from the "sandbox"
2. And now you want to expose a member of window object with your functionality:

   ```
    new Function("window", "with(window){" + sCode + "}")({
        'alert':function(sString){document.title = sString}
    });
   ```

---

Indeed you can add quotes escaping and make other polishing, but I guess the idea is clear.

Comment: Aren't there a myriad of other ways to get at the global object? For example within a function called using func.apply(null) "this" will be the window object.

Comment: The first example doesn't fail, this is a very invalid example of sandboxing.

Comment: var sCode = "this.alert('FAIL')";

Answer (score -4):

Where is this user JavaScript code coming from?

There is not much you can do about a user embedding code into your page and then calling it from their browser (see [Greasemonkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey)). It's just something browsers do.

However, if you store the script in a database, then retrieve it and eval() it, then you can clean up the script before it is run.

Examples of code that removes all window. and document. references:

```
 eval(
  unsafeUserScript
    .replace(/\/\/.+\n|\/\*.*\*\/, '') // Clear all comments
    .replace(/\s(window|document)\s*[\;\)\.]/, '') // Removes window. Or window; or window)
 )
```

This tries to prevent the following from being executed (not tested):

```
window.location = 'http://example.com';
var w = window;
```

There are a lot of limitations you would have to apply to the unsafe user script. Unfortunately, there isn't any 'sandbox container' available for JavaScript.

Comment: If someone is trying to do something malicious a simple regex just can't do it -- take

    (function(){this["loca"+"tion"]="http://example.com";})()

In general if you can't trust your users (which is the case with any site on which arbitrary people can add content) blocking all js is necessary.

Comment: I've used something similar in the past. It's not perfect, but it gets you most of the way there.

Comment: olliej, you are right about the limitations of such a technique. How about overwriting global variables like <code>var window = null, document = null, this = {};</code>?

Comment: Dimitry Z, overwriting these variables is not allowed [in some browsers]. Also check on my solution in the list of answers - it works.

Answer (score -5):

I've been working on a simplistic JavaScript sandbox for letting users build applets for my site. Although I still face some challenges with allowing DOM access (parentNode just won't let me keep things secure =/), my approach was just to redefine the window object with some of its useful/harmless members, and then eval() the user code with this redefined window as the default scope.

My "core" code goes like this... (I'm not showing it entirely ;)

```
function Sandbox(parent){

    this.scope = {
        window: {
            alert: function(str){
                alert("Overriden Alert: " + str);
            },
            prompt: function(message, defaultValue){
                return prompt("Overriden Prompt:" + message, defaultValue);
            },
            document: null,
            .
            .
            .
            .
        }
    };

    this.execute = function(codestring){

        // Here some code sanitizing, please

        with (this.scope) {
            with (window) {
                eval(codestring);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

So, I can instantiate a Sandbox and use its *execute()* function to get code running. Also, all new declared variables within eval'd code will ultimately bound to the execute() scope, so there will not be clashing names or messing with existing code.

Although global objects will still be accessible, those which should remain unknown to the sandboxed code must be defined as proxies in the Sandbox::scope object.

Comment: This does not sandbox anything.
The evaled code can delete members and get to the global scope that way, or grab a reference to ghe global scope by doing (function () { return this; })()

Answer (score -6):

You can wrap the user's code in a function that redefines forbidden objects as parameters -- these would then be `undefined` when called:

```
(function (alert) {

alert ("uh oh!"); // User code

}) ();
```

Of course, clever attackers can get around this by inspecting the JavaScript DOM and finding a non-overridden object that contains a reference to the window.

---

Another idea is scanning the user's code using a tool like [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/). Make sure it's set to have no preset variables (or: only variables you want), and then if any globals are set or accessed do not let the user's script be used. Again, it might be vulnerable to walking the DOM -- objects that the user can construct using literals might have implicit references to the window object that could be accessed to escape the sandbox.

Comment: If the user entered window.alert instead of plain alert, they would bypass that limit.

Comment: @Dorward: yes, hence "forbidden objects". wrunsby should decide what objects the user is not allowed to access, and place them in the parameter list.

Comment: There is only one object - window. If you don't block access to it, then everything is available through it. If you do block it, then the script can't access anything of its properties (since saying alert instead of window.alert just implies the window.).

Comment: @Doward: that isn't the case you would block window.alert but alert would still work, try it. This is because window is also the global object. One would need to block window and any property or method of window you didn't want the user code to access.