# Overwriting Native Methods in Javascript

Tags: javascript, native-methods, overwrite

I'm doing some analysis of some Javascript and I want to keep javascript enabled, but disable all alert() boxes and self.location redirects.

Currently I'm using a regex proxy, but that seems like overkill.

I can override some native methods but not others in Firefox i.e.

```
window.alert = function('') { return null; }
alert('test!') // works as expected
```

However when I try to similarly overwrite window.location = (which is an alias for the method call window.assign() ) it does not work

```
window.location.assign = function('') { return null; }
window.location.assign('#') // redirects :(
```

I've tried setting Window.prototype.location.assign but i get a "Cannot modify properties of a WrappedNative" exception.

Any alternatives to NoScript for fine grained JS control, or is it possible to overwrite certain Native JS methods?

Comment: Why would you want to be able to do this?  I've seen alert and confirm overwritten to create custom dialogs, but why overwrite location?

Comment: working with some malicious code

Answer (score 2):

This [suggested solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195149/is-it-possible-to-sandbox-javascript-running-in-the-browser/195153#195153) for disabling `alert` might work.