# Running raw javascript (from plain text)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to execute JavaScript from plain text (from being entered by a client).  I also need a way to see if the executed code works or not (if it does, then it does, otherwise, it needs to spit out a non-variable error message).

Thanks if you can!  The stuff that will be executed would be short strings such as:

```
echo("a","b")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use eval and wrap around try-catch.

```
try
  {
    eval(code);
  }
catch(err)
  {
  //Handle errors here
  }
```

Comment: For better security, check out some JavaScript sandboxing techniques: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195149/is-it-possible-to-sandbox-javascript-running-in-the-browser

Answer (score 5):

Are you saying you just need a try/catch statement?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch