# Which keywords should I filter in eval()?

Tags: javascript, security, eval, code-injection, jsfiddle

I need to use eval() for a JavaScript-based web app I'm building.

The reason for this is that I want to let people write their own functions that get stored as text, and can be re-used on the site when then need to use them another time. Think along the lines of jsFiddle.

The code will either be run and eval'ed, or will inserted as a script tag. Either way, it leaves the site open to JavaScript injection by malicious users. As such, I'm planning to either filter submitted code, or when a user loads another user's script, have a warning message that the user should first read / check the script before continuing.

So far, I'm looking to filter / warn on the following keywords:

```
eval
execScript

script

window.*
setInterval
setTimeout
alert
confirm
prompt

document.*
write
innerHTML
insertAdjacentHTML
createElement
appendChild
setAttribute

form.*
submit

XMLHttpRequest

jQuery.*
ajax

base64encode
base64decode
```

I've not started testing yet, so these are only my initial thoughts.

Anyone got experience or opinion on this?

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: I don't think jsfiddle uses `eval`.

Comment: Filtering submitted code would be pointless.  People will find their way around a blacklist.  What do you plan to do if someone uses "eval" in a string literal?  How will you determine which strings are used as output, and which are used to circumvent your sandbox?

Comment: Bad things bout to happen here.

Comment: Letting users run custom Javascript is a **Bad Idea**. Filtering can be easily overcome.

Comment: This, sir, is a terrible idea. Think about this for a second - `self[['a', 'lert'].join('')] ("BOO");` - I just got around your filter. And I can continue doing so as long as I can see your code, which of course since it's JS I can..

Comment: I know this doesn't address your problem, but: Avoid to use eval, use: var f = new Function("your function code"); f();

Comment: @alcidesqueiroz How does that solve anything?

Comment: @cdhowie I agree, I'm not giving a solution, but a tip. Eval isn't a good practice.

Comment: @cdhowie: AFAIK `new Function` creates a new scope and doesn't have access to the local variables of the current scope while `eval` does, so `new Function` seems more "secure".

Comment: @alcidesqueiroz: Good example, you just found the first hole in his blacklist - he only prevents `eval`

Comment: @elclanrs So?  It would still have access to the `window` global.  `new Function()` would only hide the current scope, but this assumes that the things in the current scope are the real problem.  (Hint: they're not.)

Comment: Well, thanks loads everyone for the comments; I've certainly got some directions to explore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty much any filtering can be got around by [doing this](http://patriciopalladino.com/blog/2012/08/09/non-alphanumeric-javascript.html). You're going to have to sandbox the Javascript. Possible approaches include:

- [ADsafe](http://www.adsafe.org/)
- [google-caja](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/)

Comment: There's a bunch of great replies on this post about sandboxing JavaScript. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195149/is-it-possible-to-sandbox-javascript-running-in-the-browser

Thanks, you tipped me off to it :)

Answer (score 8):

There is no way to make this safe - the characters `[]()+!{}` can be used to construct any arbitrary Javascript code.

http://patriciopalladino.com/blog/2012/08/09/non-alphanumeric-javascript.html

As far as I am aware, jsFiddle works by running user-generated code within an iframe on another domain. It does not use input filtering.

Comment: Yup - I realised this just after posting.