# Can I run a JavaScript in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is It Possible to Sandbox JavaScript Running In the Browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195149/is-it-possible-to-sandbox-javascript-running-in-the-browser)

I would like to give the user the ability to input JavaScript in a textarea like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <script>
        function lapzwans()
        {
          var d = document.getElementById("area").value;
          document.getElementById("blahblah").innerHTML = d;
        }
      </script>
    </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Javascript in Javascript</h1>
    <p>This experiment attempts to launch a script from another script.</p>
    <p>Enter your script in the text area</p>
    <textarea type="text" id="area"></textarea>
    <button onclick="lapzwans()">Click here</button>
    <p id="blahblah"></p>
    <p id="deegroller">Make this text green</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have tried this, but I get no result.
Is it impossible to do this, or am I doing things wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use an eval() function to run a javascript code, instead of just placing it as a plain text

Comment: @Fratyr Please don't suggest dangerous habbits.

Comment: A dangerous habit question was asked. And  with JavaScript, you can run any code you want in console, without eval being used by the owner..

Comment: @Daedalus `eval()` is an actual answer. Dangerous or not, for this question, it's an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible answer:

```
eval(/* some JS here */);
```

Note though that what you are trying to do can be dangerous (in some cases) as you are allowing user-written arbitrary JS to be executed.

Related reading:

- [How evil is eval?](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/how-evil-is-eval/)
- [When is JavaScript's `eval()` not evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil)

Answer (score 1):

the eval method takes whatever string is passed to it and tries to run it.

```
eval("alert('foo')");
```

will alert "foo";

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the evil eval to do this.

```
function lapzwans()
{
       var d=document.getElementById("area").value;
       document.getElementById("blahblah").innerHTML=d;

       var userScript = new Function(d);
       userScript();
}
```

Comment: How is this for any practical purposes different from `eval()`?

Comment: It's not at all, there's nothing wrong with showing someone two wrong ways to do something though.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that. I was objecting to calling `eval()` evil then doing the same basic thing.

Comment: Calling eval evil was sarcastic. His question is the definition of eval. As an example ("Don't kill him, murder him instead").

Comment: Thanks but this does not work form me. However evil eval works fine.