# Dynamic variables, scope, sandbox?

Tags: javascript, scope, sandbox, dynamic-variables

There is a need to perform an anonymous function (on the client) to a limited scope with its own environment variables (without access to the global variables). 
Overriding context **this** is not a problem, but with variable I see only one option - a **eval**. But as eval should be left to the edge, I decided to ask the community if there are other solutions to the problem.

Actually the problem:

```
function sandbox(fn){ // with eval
   fn = fn.toString();
   // need to dynamically create variables inside fn 
   fn = '(function(){"use strict"; var window, document; (' + fn + ').call(this);}) ';
   fn = eval(fn);
   fn.call({}); // example
}

sandbox(function(){
   console.log(window, document, this); // return undefined, undefined, Object {}
});
```

For a redefinition of the variables must respond to the function **sandbox()**. I mean the one with a clear redefinition of variables within functions are not transmitted to offer. Dining with the dynamic creation of the frame with its own environment, as well as transferring variable parameters to a function

```
(function(window, document){...})(null, null)
```

also not suitable for it, and so everything is clear, and is needed here dynamization of this process by the **sandbox()**. 
There are other ways to solve without using **eval**?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is It Possible to Sandbox JavaScript Running In the Browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195149/is-it-possible-to-sandbox-javascript-running-in-the-browser)

Comment: Note, the eval solution doesn't actually protect `window` or `document`. E.g. suppose `fn = ")};window.close()//"`

Comment: @vldmir - Nicely asked question, BTW.  But there are some great answers out there already for it.

Comment: @p.s.w.g - This is example. You can override all methods of window.
The question is, how to do without eval.

Comment: @Jeremy J Starcher - I'm interested in the possible implementation of the native methods