# Creating a shell for a web app

Tags: javascript, security, web, browser, emulation

I'm trying to figure out the best and most secure way to implement a shell that interacts with a web app. Here's the outline of an example problem:

1- There are several objects residing in a javascript array (e.g. `[obj1, obj2, ...]`) and each has a set of methods (e.g. `obj.setName(name), obj.getName()`).

2- I'd like to have an input field where the user can interact with the objects in a python-like language:

```
o = webApp.getObjByIndex(0)
print(o.getName())
```

As far as I can tell, my main option is to build a simple interpreter in javascript where it gets input lines one-by-one, parses it and then try to execute it. However it gets quickly complicated when implementing more features like a `for` loop.

My questions are:

- Is there a better way? Are there tools for creating domain specific languages (DSL) that javascript can understand?
- Is it possible to implement two-way python-javascript interaction in a web app?
- I'm sure there must be website implementing similar ideas. Do you know any good examples?

Thanks.

Comment: All browsers have a JS console already.  Certainly if you have a user tech savvy enough to write JS, they can figure out how to open the JS console and write their code there.

Comment: Well, the shell is supposed to be part of the main interface of the web page, where it replaces many buttons and widgets. I prefer users not open a JS console to use the website. Plus, the audience are scientists who generally know python and I think a python pseudo-shell will be familiar for them.

Comment: You probably won't find a python interpreter but this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195149/is-it-possible-to-sandbox-javascript-running-in-the-browser) might be useful to you.

Comment: Thanks! I found it interesting.