# Using promise to work with web worker inside a JavaScript closure

Tags: javascript, image-processing, es6-promise, web-worker

I was executing an image processing operation in JavaScript which was working as expected expect one thing that sometimes it was freezing the UI, which made me to use Web worker to excute the image processing functions.
I have a scenario where i need to process multiple. Below is a summary of workflow which i am using to achieve the above feat.

```
//closure
var filter = (function(){
    function process(args){
         var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            if (typeof (Worker) !== "undefined") {
                if (typeof (imgWorker) == "undefined") {
                    imgWorker = new Worker("/processWorker.js");
                }
                imgWorker.postMessage(args);
                imgWorker.onmessage = function (event) {
                    resolve(event.data);
                };
            } else {
                reject("Sorry, your browser does not support Web Workers...");
            }
        });
        return promise;
    }
return {
        process: function(args){
            return process(args);
       }
 }
})(); 

function manipulate(args, callback){
    filter.process(args).then(function(res){
        callback(res);
    });
}
```

Here, i am loading multiple images and passing them inside **manipulate** function.
The issue i am facing here in this scenario is that sometimes for few images Promise is not never resolved.
After debugging my code i figured out that it is because i am creating a Promise for an image while previous Promise was not resolved.
I need suggestions on how can i fix this issue, also i have another query should i use same closure(filter here in above scenario) multiple times or create new closure each time when required as below:

```
var filter = function(){
      ....
    return function(){}
    ....

} 

function manipulate(args, callback){
    var abc = filter();
    abc.process(args).then(function(res){
        callback(res);
    });
}
```

I hope my problem is clear, if not please comment.

Comment: Instead of `return function...` I assume that was supposed to be `var process = function...`

Comment: Yes, you are right. But that last part of code is to explain my second query only.

Comment: If you are interested in just functions that run in workers and getting the result in a promise have a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/worker-function. It hides the complexity of messges and working with workers in their own file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A better approach would be to load your image processing `Worker` once only. during the start of your application or when it is needed.

After that, you can create a Promise only for the function you wish to call from the worker. In your case, `filter` can return a new `Promise` object every time that you post to the `Worker`. This promise object should only be resolved when a reply is received from the worker for the specific function call.

What is happening with your code is that, your promises are resolving even though the `onmessage` handler is handling a different message from the Worker. ie. if you post 2 times to the worker. if the second post returns a message it automatically resolves both of your promise objects.

I created a worker encapsulation here [Orc.js](https://github.com/miozzz/sandbox/tree/master/orc). Although it may not work out of the box due to the fact i haven't cleaned it of some dependencies i built into it. Feel free to use the methods i applied.

Additional: 
You will need to map your `post` and `onmessage` to your `promises`. this will require you to modify your Worker code as well.

```html
//
let generateID = function(args){
  //generate an ID from your args. or find a unique way to distinguish your promises. 
  return id;
}
let promises =  {}
// you can add this object to your filter object if you like. but i placed it here temporarily

//closure
var filter = (function(){
    function process(args){
          let id = generateID(args)
          promises[id] = {}
          promises[id].promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            if (typeof (Worker) !== "undefined") {
                if (typeof (imgWorker) == "undefined") {
                    imgWorker = new Worker("/processWorker.js");
                    imgWorker.onmessage = function (event) {
                        let id = generateID(event.data.args) //let your worker return the args so you can check the id of the promise you created.
                        // resolve only the promise that you need to resolve
                        promises[id].resolve(event.data);
                    }    
                    // you dont need to keep assigning a function to the onmessage. 
                }
               
                imgWorker.postMessage(args);
                // you can save all relevant things in your object. 
                promises[id].resolve = resolve
                promises[id].reject = reject
                promises[id].args = args
            } else {
                reject("Sorry, your browser does not support Web Workers...");
            }
        });
        //return the relevant promise
        return promises[id].promise;
    }
return {
        process: function(args){
            return process(args);
       }
}
})(); 

function manipulate(args, callback){
    filter.process(args).then(function(res){
        callback(res);
    });
}
```

Comment: i believe, i am using creating image processing worker and assigning it to a global variable only once and next time using that global worker again. 
I have posted wrong code and now i have modified please review the code again.

Comment: `imgWorker.onmessage = function (event) {
                    resolve(event.data);
                };`
this is the problem here. 
you have to check which `post` your worker is replying to.

Comment: Yes, You are right. Now, In order to map each promise to its corresponding resolve/reject i m passing an unique id to each post message and storing resolve/reject in an object with their unique id as key value.

Comment: I posted additional code but it seems you are already doing a similar approach. what seems to be the problem?

Comment: Thanks miozz for you response, i used the above approach to fix my issue, i have implemented and tested the approach. I will also try to implement your approach too.

Answer (score 0):

typescirpt equivalent on [gist](https://gist.github.com/valen214/05cf6be21a7e46d3a027dbde5b077d6e):

Combining answers from ["Webworker without external files"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5408406/3142238)
you can add functions to worker scope like the line `` `(${sanitizeThis.toString()})(this);,` `` inside Blob constructing array.

There are some problems regarding resolving promise outside of the promise enclosure, mainly about error catching and stack traces, I didn't bother because it works perfectly fine for me right now.

```js
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/37154736/3142238
function sanitizeThis(self){
  // @ts-ignore
  // console.assert(this === self, "this is not self", this, self);
  // 'this' is undefined

  "use strict";

  var current = self;
  var keepProperties = [
      // Required
      'Object', 'Function', 'Infinity', 'NaN',
      'undefined', 'caches', 'TEMPORARY', 'PERSISTENT',
      "addEventListener", "onmessage",
      // Optional, but trivial to get back
      'Array', 'Boolean', 'Number', 'String', 'Symbol',
      // Optional
      'Map', 'Math', 'Set',
      "console",
  ];

  do{
      Object.getOwnPropertyNames(
        current
      ).forEach(function(name){
        if(keepProperties.indexOf(name) === -1){
          delete current[name];
        }
      });

      current = Object.getPrototypeOf(current);
  } while(current !== Object.prototype);
}


/*
https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/07/how-fast-are-web-workers/
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview
*/
class WorkerWrapper
{
  worker;

  stored_resolves = new Map();

  constructor(func){
    let blob = new Blob([
      `"use strict";`,
      "const _postMessage = postMessage;",
      `(${sanitizeThis.toString()})(this);`,
      `const func = ${func.toString()};`,
      "(", function(){
        // self.onmessage = (e) => {
        addEventListener("message", (e) => {
          
          _postMessage({
            id: e.data.id,
            data: func(e.data.data)
          });
        })
      }.toString(), ")()"
    ], {
      type: "application/javascript"
    });
    let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    this.worker = new Worker(url);
    URL.revokeObjectURL(url);

    this.worker.onmessage = (e) => {
      let { id, data } = e.data;
      let resolve = this.stored_resolves.get(id);
      this.stored_resolves.delete(id);
      if(resolve){
        resolve(data);
      } else{
        console.error("invalid id in message returned by worker")
      }
    }
  }

  terminate(){
    this.worker.terminate();
  }

  count = 0;
  postMessage(arg){
    let id = ++this.count;
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
      this.stored_resolves.set(id, res);
      this.worker.postMessage({
        id,
        data: arg
      });
    })
  }
}

// usage

let worker = new WorkerWrapper(
  (d) => { return d + d; }
);
worker.postMessage("HEY").then((e) => {
  console.log(e); // HEYHEY
})
worker.postMessage("HELLO WORLD").then((f) => {
  console.log(f); // HELLO WORLDHELLO WORLD
})


let worker2 = new WorkerWrapper(
  (abc) => {
    // you can insert anything here,
    // just be aware of whether variables/functions are in scope or not
    return(
      {
        "HEY": abc,
        [abc]: "HELLO WORLD" // this particular line will fail with babel
        // error "ReferenceError: _defineProperty is not defined",
      }
    );
  }
);
worker2.postMessage("HELLO WORLD").then((f) => {
  console.log(f);
  /*
      {
        "HEY": "HELLO WORLD",
        "HELLO WORLD": "HELLO WORLD"
      }
  */
})

/*
observe how the output maybe out of order because
web worker is true async
*/
```