# Python cached decorator taking stale values from parameter

Tags: python

I have a python function which is caching results based on the parameter passed. The issue is, `fval()` can return different values depending on other factors. But the `test()` is still sending me stale values. How do I ensure, the parameter `v` is getting the latest values from `fval()`

```
@cached(60*5)
def test(a,v=fval()):
  print "inside function"
  return a,v

r = test(2)
inside test function
print r
(2, 5)

print fval()
7

r = test(2) . #This time I am expecting v to be 7, but it isnt
print r 
(2,5)
```

I am expecting r to print (2,7) instead. How do I ensure, latest values are being sent as a parameter to the cached function ?

Answer (score 0):

Optional values are evaluated when the function itself is evaluated [for all functions in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument). The usual solution is to provide a value that represents nothing, then check for it:

```
@cached(60*5)
def test(a, v=None):
    if v is None:
        v = fval()

    print "inside function"
    return a, v
```

If, after that, you also expect `cached` to act on the final value of `fval()` instead of the absence of a second argument, you’ll need to do something like this:

```
@cached(60*5)
def _test(a, v):
    print "inside function"
    return a, v

def test(a, v=None):
    if v is None:
        v = fval()

    return _test(a, v)
```

Comment: Hey, I thought [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195149/is-it-possible-to-sandbox-javascript-running-in-the-browser/24660713#24660713) was a useful, creative contribution that deserves to stay (it was a unique approach for a similar problem I had) - a bit odd, but a very interesting option to keep in mind, was it really unsalvageable for some reason?

Comment: @CertainPerformance: I no longer think it’s a robust approach, now that I’ve seen some of the direction web workers are going, and haven’t looked into whether it can still be a safe approach – so it’s safer for me not to recommend it at all for now. Will try to find time to check it more thoroughly. (Even when I had the same problem at a job, my main choice of defense was a sandboxed iframe, not a web worker.)

Answer (score 0):

It's because of this line:

`def test(a,v=fval()):`

In Python, default arguments are resolved once, at function definition.

You'll probably need to do something like this:

```
def test(a, v=None):
    if v is None:
        v = fval()

    # the rest here
```