# Why can't you freeze the window object?

Tags: javascript

TLDR: Why can't I do:

```
let x = Object.freeze(window)
VM431:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot freeze
    at Function.freeze (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:1:16
```

It's an object, isn't it?

```
typeof(window)
"object"
```

I know there are other Qs that deal with sandboxing JS, but this question is really just trying to understand better why freezing `window` is not allowed.

Comment: [Is It Possible to Sandbox JavaScript Running In the Browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/195149)

Comment: I have read that post. This question isn't so much "how do I sandbox" but more trying to learn why `Object.freeze(window)` is not allowed. I'll edit my question accordingly.

Comment: `Object.freeze()` does what it says. .Likely because it makes no sense to make the whole window read-only? So where the information about frozen / sealed objects is being maintained? You can't do that, because you can't do that ...

Comment: I also believe it is because `window` is readonly. You cannot assign to it like `window = 'a'` hence you can't also change it's attributes

Comment: Not all attributes on window are writable.

Answer (score 3):

because it is declared to be extensible, in fact you can create such `freeze`-less `objects` on your own like this:

```js
const someObject = new Proxy({}, {
  preventExtensions: () => {
    throw TypeError('Cannot freeze');
  }
});

someObject.x = 1;

console.log(typeof someObject);
console.log(someObject);

Object.freeze(someObject);
```

more about this you can read here: [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).

the next question may arise, why it is "made" extensible, for this we have the definition of `window` [Global object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_object), and this example:

```
var foo = "foobar";
foo === window.foo; // Returns: true
```

considering this, one may now wonder what would happen if we could `freeze` it

Comment: It is different. While trying to freeze `someObject`, Firefox says: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot freeze` while when I try to freeze window Firefox says `Uncaught TypeError: can't prevent extensions on this proxy object`

Comment: just put that message here `throw TypeError('Cannot freeze')` and you'll get the same

Comment: that is not related. I mean that freezing a `canEvolve = true` object is not the same as freezing the `window` object. Because otherwise they would throw the same error.

Comment: error messages are not standardized by the specs, they are an implementation detail, so you may note different error between browsers when trying to freeze the `window` object, since the implementation of `window` object is browser specific

Comment: They are not standard, but they are well-known. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cant_define_property_object_not_extensible) I believe there is an internal mechanism that do just that but for `window` and other native objects only.